# Generate a 3-d matrix from a vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `(N-1)x1`

```
A=[0:1:N-2]'
```

with `N>=3`, e.g. with `N=4 A=[0 1 2]`

I want to construct a 3-dimensional matrix `B` of dimension `Mx(N-1)x(N-1)` without using loops such that e.g. with `N=4`, `M=5`

```
B(:,:,1)=[0 0 0 0;
          0 0 0 0;
          0 0 0 0;
          0 0 0 0;
          0 0 0 0]

B(:,:,2)=[1 1 1 1;
          1 1 1 1;
          1 1 1 1;
          1 1 1 1;
          1 1 1 1]
```

...

```
B(:,:,end)=[N-2 N-2 N-2 N-2;
            N-2 N-2 N-2 N-2;
            N-2 N-2 N-2 N-2;
            N-2 N-2 N-2 N-2;
            N-2 N-2 N-2 N-2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
B = repmat(reshape(A,1,1,[]), M, N-1); %// or change N-1 to N, according to your example
```

Another possibility:

```
B = bsxfun(@times, reshape(A,1,1,[]), ones(M, N-1)); %// or change N-1 to N
```

Yet another:

```
B = reshape(A(ceil((1:numel(A)*M*(N-1))/M/(N-1))), M, N-1, []); %// or change N-1 to N
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach with [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) and [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
A = 0:N-2;
B = reshape(kron(A, ones(M, N-1)), M, N-1, []);
```

We use `kron` to produce `M x (N-1)` 2D matrices that are stacked for as many elements as there are in `A` and each matrix is multiplied by the corresponding value in `A`.  The next step is to take each of the concatenated 2D matrices and place them as individual slices in the third dimension, done by `reshape`.

## Example with `M = 5, N = 4`

```
>> B

B(:,:,1) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0


B(:,:,2) =

     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1


B(:,:,3) =

     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to keep using `permute` until I get the hang of it...

```
B = ones(M,N-1,N-1).*permute(A,[3,2,1])
```